# How to reference library already defined at app level in Aurelia ViewModel

Tags: aurelia, systemjs

Sytemjs is defined in index.html so technically you can do System.import from anywhere in your application and it will work.  However during the build, my component which dynamically imports a library when it is used, gives an error:

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'System'
```

Here is the component code:

```
import { bindable, bindingMode, customElement, noView } from 'aurelia-framework';

@noView()
@customElement('scriptinjector')
export class ScriptInjector {
  @bindable public url;
  @bindable public isLocal;
  @bindable public isAsync;
  @bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.oneWay }) protected scripttag;
  private tagId = 'bootTOCscript';

  public attached() {
    if (this.url) {
      if (this.isLocal) {
        System.import(this.url);
        return;
      }

      this.scripttag = document.createElement('script');
      if (this.isAsync) {
        this.scripttag.async = true;
      }

      this.scripttag.setAttribute('src', this.url);
      document.body.appendChild(this.scripttag);
    }
  }

  public detached() {
    if (this.scripttag) {
      this.scripttag.remove();
    }
  }
}
```

The project builds and runs just fine despite the error and I tried resolving this by adding:

```
import System from 'systemjs';
```

To the component which does resolve the error but at runtime, this import causes Systemjs to look for itself in the app-build bundle which is incorrect.  The System.js code is exported seperately.  Is there a way to resolve this and have no error message and have it work at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually more of a general TypeScript issue when accessing things that implicitly exist in the global scope. What you can do is to *declare* the variable without actually importing it, like so:

```
declare var System: System;
```

(The actual type of System will depend on what your .d.ts looks like)

Comment: Thank you, this worked great.  Small follow up, this other answer helped with another issue where new properties were attached to the global window object: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12709880/229250