# How to re-run module code with SystemJs

Tags: systemjs

I have a javascript library bundled using SystemJs.  It contains a self invoking anonymous function.  When I import it in on of my viewmodels (I don't want this code to run at the app level) it runs once and then when I leave and re-enter my view the module is already imported so the anonymous function does not run again.

The library I am trying to integrate is [Bootstrap-Toc](https://afeld.github.io/bootstrap-toc/) and I am trying to get it to work with Aurelia (using typescript and jspm).

Is there any way to either unload/remove a module that has been imported and then re-import it or somehow force the module to 'refresh' and thereby re-run the code?

Comment: Having instructions producing a certain logic other than function and variable definitions in a module is a serious code smell. I believe you should find another way to trigger the relating event and have that logic in a function as part of the module's API.

Comment: This library is built on Bootstrap.js which in turn relies on jquery and (I am new to web dev) it seems these self-running things seem to be standard for these types of libraries.  Is your suggestion that I should re-architect the library?

Comment: Sure those libraries might contain variable initializations, but they were not designed to be "re-included". I actually thought the module at hand was part of the project's source. Can you specify that further in the question?

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I have added the library and the project type I'm using.  Let me know what further details are needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have abandoned this approach.  For details about how I worked around needing this see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44731908/229250).